# Is Wrathful Smite's wisdom check optional?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, paladin, fear

The spell description says:

> As an action, the creature can make a Wisdom check against your spell save DC to end this spell.

Does this mean that the Wisdom check is not obligatory? It seems odd that the creature would have a choice as to whether it tries to steel its resolve.  I've been ruling it that way but being able to choose whether or not to just...live with it seems like an odd design choice.

Have I been interpreting it correctly? Is there any official word on this? I admit I may be overthinking it.

Edit: Just wanted to clarify that I know this is only relevant after the creature fails the initial save but I wasn't sure if posting the entire spell description was allowed or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yep, they can choose to use their action to try to end the spell. Spells that force you to use your action to do something say "must", rather than "can". This gives them the choice to try to end the spell, or to do something else. The Frightened condition is not particularly restrictive, so this way the target has all their options available to them.

For example, if the target was a wizard with Dispel Magic prepared, they might prefer to use Dispel Magic to try to end the spell, since they would have a much higher chance of success that way.

Answer (score 6):

Wrathful Smite description:

> The next time you hit with a melee weapon attack during this spell’s
>   duration, your attack deals an extra 1D6 psychic damage. Additionally,
>   if the target is a creature, it **must** make a Wisdom saving throw or be
>   frightened of you until the spell ends. As an action, the creature can
>   make a Wisdom check against your spell save DC to end this spell.

The creature can use it's action to make a **new save** to ***end*** the effect of the wrathful smite ***after*** it fails the initial save (which is not optional).

What it means to be frightned:

> A frightened creature has disadvantage on Ability Checks and Attack
>   rolls while the source of its fear is within line of sight.
>   The creature can’t willingly move closer to the source of its fear.

There's still a number of options to do if you can't afford to lose your action to make a new save and end the frightned condition (like casting spells that requires a saving throw against it's effect, frightned doesn't interfere with that), hence why it's optional.

Comment: For accuracy's sake, they make a check, not a save.

Answer (score 6):

## The Wisdom check is optional

It is up to the target to decide if spending an action on an attempt to end the spell is worth it.
Note that it is *not* a save, so it is very hard to apply your proficiency bonus.

## Design Intent

I was not able to find any quote from the creators why they did it this way.

Most likely it was for balance reasons; this is a single target spell with laughable damage that takes up your concentration. At least the target can't escape easily, it has to spend an action *and* has disadvantage on the checks after the initial save.